# PostgreSQL Database Migration

Tags: postgresql, migration, scripting

How can I migrate data from on PostgreSQL database to another PostgreSQL database?  Is there any technique to migrate data with SQL scripting?

Comment: There is a bulk loader utility maintained through the PostgreSQL foundation called [pg_bulkload](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbulkload).  This might do what you want.

Comment: The Navicat for PostgreSQL database admin tool can also do this sort of thing, amongst many others.

Comment: What's wrong with pg_dump/pg_restore?

Comment: Or good old SQL [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)?

Comment: I am new to database migration and the problem is that the destination database has one additional field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you migrate to a new version of PostgreSQL use pg_dump from the latest version. Anyway, this is a simple way to dump and restore :

```
pg_dump -U username -h hostname source_database | psql -U username target_database
```

Answer (score 2):

If your destination database has only one additional column, I think the simplest thing to do would be to [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) the existing database, load that dump into a completely new database, then add the new column.

An alternative might be to use the `--column-inserts` option (among others) for pg_dump. That will dump data as SQL INSERT statements with explicit column names. Those INSERT statements should work fine on tables that have had columns added.

Comment: Since plain pg_dump specifies the column names in the copy command and it is the destination database that has the added column then you shouldn't need to use the `--column-inserts` option, or an additional database either.